# Reloading JSON source using AngularJS Service

Tags: angularjs, json, reload

I'm new in AngularJS and I need your help for my first project.

I want to load data from JSON and display it in a table using ng-repeat, which actually works pretty good. However I want to allow the users to reload data in the table by reloading the JSON.

So first I load the page. I got the JSON and my table is filled. Then I edit the JSON file and save it. When I click on the reload button, the data I receive is exactly the same as what I got when I loaded the page. I thought it was the cache, so I cleaned my browser cache and set cache:false in the get request but it doesn't work.

Here is the code I have :

```
var routeApp = angular.module("app", ["ui.bootstrap", "ngRoute", "ngSanitize", "ngAnimate", "routeAppControllers"]);

routeApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/home", {
            templateUrl: "/SCAP/scap/resources/templates/home.html",
            controller: "ctrlHome"
        })
        .when("/dgroups", {
            templateUrl: "/SCAP/scap/resources/templates/device-groups.html",
            controller: 'ctrlDeviceGroups'
        })
        .when("/templates", {
            templateUrl: "/SCAP/scap/resources/templates/templates.html",
            controller: 'ctrlTemplates'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home'
        });
});

var routeAppControllers = angular.module('routeAppControllers', []);

routeAppControllers.controller('ctrlDeviceGroups', function ($scope, groupsService) {

    $scope.dgroups = [];

    var promise = groupsService.getGroups();
    promise.then(function(data) {
        $scope.dgroups = data;
    });

    $scope.reloadJSON = function() {
        $scope.dgroups = [];
        console.log("Cleaning all data...");
        console.log("Reloading JSON");
        var promise = groupsService.getGroups();
        promise.then(function(data) {
            $scope.dgroups = data;
            console.log("New JSON loaded");
            console.log(data);
        });
    }

}).service('groupsService', function($http, $q, $sce) {

    var json_file = "json.json";
    // Add to use that because it didn't trust the domain...
    var trustedUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(json_file);
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    console.log("Loading JSON...");
    $http(
        {
            method: 'GET',
            url: trustedUrl,
            cache: false
        }).then(function(data) {
        deferred.resolve(data.data);
    });

    this.getGroups = function() {
        return deferred.promise;
    }
});
```

Here is the HTML (I removed useless lines):

```
<div ng-controller="ctrlDeviceGroups">
<button ng-click="reloadJSON()">Reload entire table</button>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="item in dgroups">
    <!--TD-->
</tr>

</tbody>


</table></div>
```

If you have any idea of how to reload the JSON and the view I would be very grateful. I also noticed, but this is not the subject of the topic, that if I push data in my $scope.dgroups, the ng-repeat doesn't refresh.

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the GET request into the service method:

```
app.service('groupsService', function($http, $sce) {

    var json_file = "json.json";
    // Add to use that because it didn't trust the domain...
    var trustedUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(json_file);

    this.getGroups = function() {
        console.log("Loading JSON...");
        var config = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: trustedUrl,
            cache: false
        };
        return $http(config)
          .then(function(response) {
            return response.data;
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: It seems to work now !! So if I understand,  my service just fetched the file once and each time I called getGroups it was the same data.

Comment: Services are singletons. They are constructed only once. The GET request was erroneously executed only once. It needed to be done inside the `getGroups` method to be executed on each call to that method.

Comment: So I assume my service is kind of useless now? I will use it to load all my jsons, by passing the url as a parameter.